# Regexp to match between different delimters

Tags: regex, go

I need to get string between two delimters. And these pair of delimters are different. Here is my text:

```
[2018.07.10 00:30:03:640][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->StartExecuteTask\35
[2018.07.10 00:30:18:585][TraceID: 8707HFH7NR6307]->RequestInfo\27
[2018.07.10 00:30:18:585][TraceID: 8707HFH7NR6307]->RequestExecuteEnd\16
[2018.07.10 00:30:18:585][TraceID: 8707HFH7NR6307]->OutgoingData\26651
[2018.07.10 00:31:16:773][TraceID: G8EM5LANBPC32H]->CheckUserInfo\141
```

I need to get time, traceid and requset type (after -> before \{d} )

And here is my regexp:

```
[\[|\->](.*?)[\\|\]]
```

What i get:

```
2018.07.10 00:30:03:640   TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91  >StartExecuteTask
2018.07.10 00:30:18:585   TraceID: 8707HFH7NR6307  >RequestInfo
```

I can't remove the `>` from last match. Or maybe whole regexp is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\[|->)(.*?)[\\\]]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oYGTyM/1)

In Go, declare as

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\[|->)(.*?)[\\\]]`)
```

**Details**

- `(?:\[|->)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches either `[` char or `->` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars, other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `[\\\]]` - a `\` or `]` char.

[Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/y2tm3cNTR02):

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\[|->)(.*?)[\\\]]`)
    var str = `[2018.07.10 00:30:03:640][TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91]->StartExecuteTask\35`

    for _, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match[1])
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
2018.07.10 00:30:03:640
TraceID: 8HRWSI105YVO91
StartExecuteTask
```

Comment: Thx! Work perfectly!